# How to call a condition on a view?

Tags: java, android, view, onclick, conditional-statements

I have two activities in first activity, I have two text views fromLocation and toLocation. On click of from and to text view I am calling next activity in which I have a map and I choose a location which I am storing in string and showing on text view. This choose location I want to show on fromLocation text view of first activity onClick of a layout of useLocation in second activity on the basis of which text view is choose. If onClick of fromLocation the address should show on fromLocation text view and onClick of toLocation address should show on toLocation. This will be onResume method of first activity.

Now I am getting the address on both text views when I choose address for first time onClick on fromLocation text view.

How to do this..?

GoSendActivity(FirstActivity)

```
 public class GoSend extends AppCompatActivity implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private TextView additionalContactFrom,additionalContactTo,txt_from,txt_to;

    private LinearLayout linearLayoutFrom,linearLayoutTo;
    private ImageView next;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private EditText locdetailsFrom,locdetailsTo,itemDetails;
    private Intent i;
    private LatLng currentLocation,curentpoint,center;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    double latitude,longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gosendlayout);

        setUI();

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
            // not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            // Create a new global location parameters object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

            /*
             * Set the update interval
             */
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Use high accuracy
            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
            mUpdatesRequested = false;

            /*
             * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
             * callbacks.
             */
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }
    }

    public void setUI() {

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("COURIER");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        locdetailsFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_from_details);
        locdetailsFrom.setText(GoSendData.instance.getmFromLocationDetails());

        locdetailsTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_to_details);
        locdetailsTo.setText(GoSendData.instance.getmToLocationDetails());

        itemDetails = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ItemDetail);

        txt_from = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text_from);
        txt_to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text_to);
        additionalContactFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactDetailsFrom);
        additionalContactTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactDetailsTo);
        linearLayoutFrom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutFrom);
        linearLayoutTo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutTo);
        next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_next);


        txt_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickLocationActivity.class);
             ///   GoSendData.instance.addressType=0;
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        txt_to.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickLocationActivity.class);
                //GoSendData.instance.addressType=1;
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        additionalContactFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (linearLayoutFrom.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                    linearLayoutFrom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    linearLayoutFrom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        });


        additionalContactTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (linearLayoutTo.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                    linearLayoutTo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    linearLayoutTo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoSendDetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        int LocationClick;
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

            txt_from.setText(GoSendData.instance.mFromLocation);
            txt_to.setText(GoSendData.instance.mToLocation);

        }


    private void setupMap() {
        try {

            mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            gps = new GPSTracker(this);

            gps.canGetLocation();

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(curentpoint).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setupMap();

    }

          @Override
          public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }

}
```

ChooseFromMapActivity(second activity)

```
public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
    private LatLng center,curentpoint;
    private LinearLayout markerLayout,useLocation;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private TextView Address;
    double latitude,longitude;
    private GPSTracker gps;

    Intent intent;
    double x, y;
    StringBuilder str;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);


        SetUpUI();

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
            // not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            // Create a new global location parameters object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

            /*
             * Set the update interval
             */
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Use high accuracy
            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
            mUpdatesRequested = false;

            /*
             * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
             * callbacks.
             */
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        useLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,GoSend.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

        private void SetUpUI(){


            Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);
            markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);
            useLocation = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearUseLoc);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("CHOOSE FROM MAP");
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);

            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            }


}
    private void stupMap() {
        try {

            mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            gps = new GPSTracker(this);

            gps.canGetLocation();

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(curentpoint).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


            mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try {
                        new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                .execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stupMap();

    }

    private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // boolean duplicateResponse;


        public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            x = latitude;
            y = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                str = new StringBuilder();
                if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {

                    if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {
                        Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                        String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                        String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                        String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                        String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                        str.append(localityString + "");
                        str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                        str.append(zipcode + "");



                    }
                } else {
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
                GoSendData.instance.mFromLocation=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";
                GoSendData.instance.mToLocation=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)+"";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly.. You should launch second activity as `startActivityForResult` and after choosing location on map return it as a result. 
The first activity should now this value from the method `onActivityResult`

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

1. Click on first textview launch second activity with requestcode
2. Second activity after choosing location finishes with `setResult`, where you store chosen location
3. Get the result in `onActivityResult` of first activity and set it to textView

the same for second textview. Use different requestcodes for different textview, which you should check in `onActivityResult` to determine which textView data was chosen in second activity

Comment: Thank you for reply.. I have read this and tried to do.. This is what i have did in first activity ::::    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if(requestCode==1)
        {
            txt_from.setText(GoSendData.instance.mFromLocation);
        }
        else if(requestCode==2){
            txt_to.setText(GoSendData.instance.mToLocation);
        }
    }

Comment: I got confused about how should I return the result from second activity.. Because two results I have to pass depending on which text view is clicked.. how to do? @aelimill

Comment: Use setResult(some_data) and finish in second activity. Not the static field on GoSendData. As i can understand the second activity just get coordinates, you do not need to know which textview was pressed. You just pass chosen coordinates to data and finishes this activity.

Comment: Actually i have another activity in between. Can you please explain me through code?@aelimill